# Calculator with one input in php

Tags: php

I want to make a calculator in PHP with one input field and one submit button.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" name="text1">
        <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

suppose, if i want add then i will give input 10+12 in the single input and when i will click in submit button it will show result.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["btnSubmit"])){
    $a=$_POST["text1"];
    if($a+$a){
        echo $a+$a;
    }elseif($a-$a){
        echo $a-$a;
    }elseif($a*$a){
        echo $a*$a;
    }elseif($a/$a){
        echo $a/$a;
    }else{
        echo "false";
    }
}

?>
```

i tried a of time but cannot to make the logic.

Comment: So, when person will enter 2. Then, on what basis it will addition/subtraction. And, atleast, 2 number needed to perform calculation? What is the idea behind it.?

Comment: Start from what you think `if($a+$a){` should do

Comment: The code is all kinds of wrong. The ifs particularly annoy me. In php http://php.net/manual/ro/language.types.boolean.php those values do not do what you expect them to do. You have some more reading to do.

Comment: i want anyone will enter 2+3 and will get output. @Nana Partykar

Comment: as i want one input filed and will get i input thats way i write $a+$a.but this is not the right logic i know.Just trying@Federkun

Comment: If more than 2 numbers? Then?

Comment: Actually i don't think about this. Thx a lot. Actually it should be more than 2,3 number whatever we want.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to **evaluate** the string a user gives like this:

```
<?php

// Initialise $POST['text1'] for testing purpose
$POST['text1'] = '12*-10';

// IMPORTANT ---------------------------------------------------------------
// It could be dangerous to evaluate text input by a user.
// So, we make sure to evaluate input of the form
// "numeric_value operator numeric_value" only.
// IMPORTANT ---------------------------------------------------------------
if (preg_match('%^[\d-+.]*?[-+*/]{1,1}[\d-+.]*$%', $POST['text1'])) {
    // Prepare a PHP statement containing the user's term.
    // I.e. "return a + b;"
    $term = 'return ' . $POST['text1'] . ';';
    // Evaluate the statement now.
    $res = eval($term);
    if ($res!==false) {
        // Evaluation done correctly.
        echo $res;
    } else {
        // Error in PHP statement.
        echo 'Illegal term. Format "numeric_value operator numeric_value"';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Illegal characters in term';
}

?>
```

Notes:

- *eval* is an **elegant** approach in this case.
- It is also a **dangerous** solution if you do not make sure that only appropriate expressions are evaluated. Otherwise the user's input could be harmful, as he/she could have your script execute **any** possible PHP statement. Therefore the code makes sure only expected input is processed:
  *if (preg_match(...))*

This is what the *regex* in *preg_match* does:

> ```
> ^[\d-+.]*?[-+*/]{1,1}[\d-+.]*$
>
> Assert position at the beginning of the string «^»
> Match a single character present in the list below «[\d-+.]*?»
>    Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
>    A single digit 0..9 «\d»
>    One of the characters “-+.” «-+.»
> Match a single character present in the list below «[\d-+*/]{1,1}»
>    Exactly 1 times «{1,1}»
>    One of the characters “-+*/” «-+*/»
> Match a single character present in the list below «[\d-+.]*»
>    Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
>    A single digit 0..9 «\d»
>    One of the characters “-+.” «-+.»
> Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any) «$»
> ```

Comment: I was about to write answer using eval(). But, your answer is better than what I was trying. *Thumbs Up*

Comment: @NanaPartykar: Thank you for the flowers.

Answer (score 1):

You Can try This Approach Using eval and Loop array:

```
$string = '61+6-55*1+2-14+1';
    $num = preg_split("/[^0-9]+/", $string);
    $op = (array_filter(preg_split("/[0-9]+/", $string)));
    $a = $num[0];
    $res = 0;
    foreach ($op as $key => $val) {
        $b = $num[$key];
        $res = eval("return $a $val $b;");
        $a = $res;
    }
    var_dump($res);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should do in the following way because in the if clause your evaluation should be boiled all the way down to either true or false. but your current calculation in the if and elseif clauses aren't doing that.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["btnSubmit"])){
    $a = $_POST["text1"];



    // first get the what operator you have
    // extract the first number or the numbers left side of the operator
    // extract the last number or the numbers right side of the operator
    $operator = false;
    if (stripos($a, "+")) {
        $operator = substr($a, stripos($a, "+"), 1);
        $firstNumber = substr($a, 0, stripos($a, "+"));
        $lastNumber = substr($a, stripos($a, "+")+1);
    } elseif (stripos($a, "-")) {
        $operator = substr($a, stripos($a, "-"), 1);
        $firstNumber = substr($a, 0, stripos($a, "-"));
        $lastNumber = substr($a, stripos($a, "-")+1);
    } elseif (stripos($a, "*")) {
        $operator = substr($a, stripos($a, "*"), 1);
        $firstNumber = substr($a, 0, stripos($a, "*"));
        $lastNumber = substr($a, stripos($a, "*")+1);
    } elseif (stripos($a, "/")) {
        $operator = substr($a, stripos($a, "/"), 1);
        $firstNumber = substr($a, 0, stripos($a, "/"));
        $lastNumber = substr($a, stripos($a, "/")+1);
    }

     // make sure that user submited operator is one of the above operators
    if ($operator == false)
        die("Wrong operator");




   if($operator == '+') {
        echo ($firstNumber + $lastNumber);
    } else if ($operator == '-') {
        echo ($firstNumber - $lastNumber);
    } else if ($operator == '*') {
        echo ($firstNumber * $lastNumber);
    } else if ($operator == '/') {
        echo ($firstNumber / $lastNumber);
    } else {
        echo "false";
    }
}
```

[substr function documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_substr.asp)

[stripos documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_stripos.asp)

Comment: thx a lot but its only working for addition. It doesn't work for subtraction, multiplication or division.

Comment: i have already done by taking help from your  last help.but thanks a lot for your fully support. Thanks Again